# Plain Java library in Android Studio giving compile error inside the editor: Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I started working on an Android project in kotlin using clean architecture with a data and a domain layer, the domain layer is a plain java-library (no android dependencies)

This is the Domain module relevant gradle conf:

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id("kotlin")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

dependencies {
    api(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    // ....
}
```

If I run a build from command line or within android studio it finish **SUCCESSFULLY!**

BUT Android Studio gives me lot of weird errors **in the EDITOR** only for this module:

```
Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.Double'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.String'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'java.util.Locale'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'java.math.BigDecimal'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'java.time.OffsetDateTime'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

Here, look:
[image]

You get the picture. They are all in red **in the Editor**. However, if I execute compile: no error, and **the project work as expected**.

I want to stress this out:

> --> **It is just a problem in the Editor** BUT it is annoying <--

Cause it hides real errors I might need to see.

The other Dev in the project has no such issues.

I'm running on the last Android Studio Beta:

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 3
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7395685, built on May 25, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.8.0-53-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.intellij.lang.jsgraphql, org.intellij.plugins.markdown
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
```

I'm on Linux as you see, Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS to be precise. The other Dev have a mac.

Android studio is set to use **Embedded JDK** (which is version 11).

If I edit my settings and instead of using the Embedded JDK I switch to my system openjdk version 11 the errors go away

When I change it, however, I start to have some preview issues in compose and, anyway,  the Embedded JDK is [recommended by Google](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#jdk). I'd rather stick to it, quoting:

> A copy of the latest OpenJDK comes bundled with Android Studio 2.2 and
> higher, and this is the JDK version we recommend you use for your
> Android projects.

Can anyone give any insight or help in getting rid of the above mentioned errors?

Comment: have you tried compiling manually? maybe is intellij that has an invalid cache... try fiel > invalidate cache and restart

Comment: I said the compilation is successful. The problem is only error in the editors. It's annoying, that's it. I'm gonna edit my question to make it more clear

Comment: I've been having the same problem with IntelliJ IDEA and Kotlin. Perhaps they messed something up in a recent release.

Comment: I've added a tag for intellij-idea, thanks @Slaw if you find a solution please come back here and share it

Comment: Seems like a bug in latest AS: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-7627. I'll ping the Kotlin IDE plugin team.

Comment: @Alexey If it helps at all, I haven't seen the error in IntelliJ IDEA when coding a "normal" Kotlin project, at least not yet. I saw the error when trying to write a custom Gradle plugin in Kotlin (I think both in `buildSrc` and standalone, but could have been one or the other) and trying to access the Kotlin DSL API (but everything compiled and executed fine, if I remember correctly).

Comment: Do you have any updates @Alexey Belkov?

Comment: This issue report might help you: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213131387

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like Android Studio's indices are broken. Try the following steps:

1. Sync the project with gradle (I believe that's the button in the top right with the elephant icon)
2. If the issue still persists, go to "File" -> "Repair IDE" and see if that fixes the problem.
3. If the issue still persists, go to "File" -> "Invalidate caches" -> "Invalidate and restart"

Answer (score -3):

The same issue with you.
When I create a use a separate module, it has this visual error. It's gone when not use a module.